# Why is google analytics not calculating revenue correctly?

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

I researched and tried all I know to fix the GA4 tracking but I can't seem solve it.
GA4 is not handling my tickets for more than a month.

In my website, users make purchases and I want to show accurate revenue in GA4, in SAR currency.
I use this code for successful orders:

```
            if(( typeof gtag !== 'undefined')){
                gtag("event", "purchase", {
                    transaction_id: "{{$order->paymentid}}",
                    affiliation: "My Store",
                    value: +('{{$theTotal}}'.replace(',','')),
                    tax: {{$order->vat}},
                    shipping: {{$theShipping}},
                    currency: "{{$order->currency}}",
                    coupon: "{{$order->coupon_code}}",
                    items: temp
                });
            }
```

and it's rendered like this:
[image]

and when I check GA4 dashboard, I find 0 revenue or a single revenue out of more than 10 orders. Although my client-to-server logs prove that they all succeeded.

Here is a screenshot from GA4 on a specific date:
[image]

And here are the logs showing that my store received 9 successful orders:
[image]

**Can you tell me why GA4 takes a single or none "purchase" events and ignores the rest?**

**EDIT:**

To clarify more, here are the tags I have in the head:
[image]

And here is a screenshot from GA4 Admin settings also:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined your custom dimensions and methods in analytics.google? remember you need to wait 48 hours after creating custom dimensions and 24 hours for custom metrics.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en&ref_topic=11151952

Comment: thanks @ShilaMosammami, my event is a standard event "purchase" and from the docs I understood it's not required to create custom dimensions for it. I mean GA4 gives me for example 514 SAR while I had more than 3000 SAR as a total of all purchase events

Comment: a stupid question since I have no idea of laravel, is your assigning syntax correct? because in normal javascript I do not use {{}} and simply I write gtag('event', 'Your Event Name', {
    'your_param1': 'value 1',
    'your_param2': 'value 2',
  });

Comment: @ShilaMosammami, I understand, check the first image I attached for the rendered html, it looks perfectly valid

Comment: ok you are right, now the only thing comes to my mind is checking if you are using the correct measure id, in analytics google go to admin, data stream and select your stream and check. the GA4 should have a measure id that starts with G-,

immidiately after <head>
   <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=yourMeasureId"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'yourMeasureId');
  </script>

Comment: @ShilaMosammami thanks for helping, I checked the code and to me they look ok but please take a look at my edit. I added more screenshots to compare my code with GA4

Comment: why have you put false value for debug_mode? just delete that.

Comment: @ShilaMosammami I tried it with true and false, it didn't affect the result. But I'll remove it

Comment: have you tries to read your values from google analytics data Api, using a programming language?I am using Java. here is the link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have marked this on:
[image]

Comment: thanks for noting, I it's disabled why? look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vs6v.png kindly note that in my question I mentioned that GA4 only takes a single or 2 orders out of the total or sometimes it takes none. so my revenue is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter `transaction_id` is not populated. It is mandatory to populate this parameter when you are sending purchase event.

Please see more here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events#purchase